# Sort CSV file that has no headers

Tags: python, csv, sorting

How to sort the csv file if there are no headers?
My data is as follows and i want to sort it by Date

```
14/09/2018      Manchester      Manchester United    Chelsea             
06/09/2018      Manchester      Manchester United    Tottenham Hotspur   
05/09/2018      Manchester      Manchester United    Liverpool           
13/09/2018      Chelsea         Chelsea              Manchester United   
10/09/2018      Chelsea         Chelsea              Tottenham Hotspur   
09/09/2018      Chelsea         Chelsea              Liverpool           
12/09/2018      Tottenham       Tottenham Hotspur    Manchester United   
08/09/2018      Tottenham       Tottenham Hotspur    Chelsea             
07/09/2018      Tottenham       Tottenham Hotspur    Liverpool           
11/09/2018      Liverpool City  Liverpool            Manchester United   
15/09/2018      Liverpool City  Liverpool            Chelsea             
04/09/2018      Liverpool City  Liverpool            Tottenham Hotspur
```

Comment: A) Give it headers. B) Sort on column 0.

Comment: Why do you need the headers? What are you aiming to sort the data into?

Comment: read the csv file, add each row to a list or dictionary. Then sort by the date index or key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use pandas for this:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('dummy.csv', names=['Date', 'City', 'Home', 'Away']) # read in csv with header assignment to columns
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date) #convert 'Dates' column to datetime
df = df.sort_values(by='Date').reset_index() # sort by date and reindex
```

output:

```
         Date            City               Home               Away
0       2018-04-09  Liverpool City          Liverpool  Tottenham Hotspur
1       2018-05-09      Manchester  Manchester United          Liverpool
2       2018-06-09      Manchester  Manchester United  Tottenham Hotspur
3       2018-07-09       Tottenham  Tottenham Hotspur          Liverpool
4       2018-08-09       Tottenham  Tottenham Hotspur            Chelsea
5       2018-09-09         Chelsea            Chelsea          Liverpool
6       2018-09-13         Chelsea            Chelsea  Manchester United
7       2018-09-14      Manchester  Manchester United            Chelsea
8       2018-09-15  Liverpool City          Liverpool            Chelsea
9       2018-10-09         Chelsea            Chelsea  Tottenham Hotspur
10      2018-11-09  Liverpool City          Liverpool  Manchester United
11      2018-12-09       Tottenham  Tottenham Hotspur  Manchester United
```

Comment: The Date column is not really sorted correctly. The unsorted dates from my list were in the range 04-Sep-2018 to 15-Sep-2018. But the output you are showing is not really sorting them correctly. Can you please fix your code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file and read it into a dictionary, if your dates are unique. If not then you'll want to find a secondary key to sort over.

```
def read_from_file(file_name):
    data = {}
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            datum = extract_data(line)
            data[get_key(datum)] = datum

def sort(data):
    return [data[key] for key in sort(data.iterkeys())]
```

In this example, there are two methods that you'll want to implement: `extract_data()` that will take a line of the file (as a string) and put that into a form you want to work with (a class or a dictionary or whatever) and `get_key` that will extract your unique key (which could be your date or your date plus something else). Note that `get_key` has to be unique for each element in your table so you should ensure that it is. Otherwise, the dictionary-sort won't work as expected.